# How to display the website notifications on system notifications using ElectronJS

Tags: html, notifications, electron

I am attempting to make a desktop application that simply mirrors a website (as shown in this demo https://www.electronjs.org/docs/latest/api/web-contents)

My question is how can I change the website notifications to show up as a system notification from the desktop application.

Any help is appreciated thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you cant. Must use other methods to send notifications to electron.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).